# 'User friendly' GUI for controlling tests using Selenium Server

Tags: java, selenium, junit, automated-tests, selenium-rc

I am using Selenium Server (specifically `selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar`) within a Java application to perform automated testing of web pages. This is all being done within the Eclipse IDE.

I understand that a conventional way to run tests using Selenium Server and Java is to use JUnit tests, with those tests being invoked from within Eclipse.

To be clear, this is not for unit testing / debugging. What I am trying to achieve here is to automate functional tests that the test team currently need to do manually when testing an embedded hardware device. This hardware device happens to have an internal web server, which provides a convenient interface through which I can use Selenium to drive the device.

The tests require a large amount of parameter input, and it is necessary for those lists of parameters to be put together by the test people who aren't very familiar with programming and IDEs. For this reason I am planning to use the Java Excel Library so that the test personnel can create the test cases by simply creating an Excel spreadsheet, which they're of course going to be very comfortable with.

What I need is some kind of user-friendly GUI that the test people could use, which would provide straightforward controls (e.g. buttons) to invoke tests and load Excel parameter sheets.

The way I am thinking of going is to abandon JUnit (as I'm not really sure what benefit it gives me in this scenario - though I'd welcome comments on that) and create a standalone Java Swing application that provides the GUI, and controls Selenium Server underneath. This would be far better for the test people than, say, having to invoke JUnit tests in Eclipse.

Before I go ahead, is there any other option I should consider? I haven't used JUnit a great deal before, and I understand that version 3 of it did have graphical runners, but these were phased out in version 4.

Comment: Is a non-programmer going to be debugging a program in development state? Really? This sounds like so much trouble.

Comment: @lzmaki No, obviously they won't be doing debugging. Test results will be logged. I shall edit my question to make it more clear that I'm trying to achieve functional tests here rather than unit tests. The purpose of this exercise is to try to automate a lot of work that the test team currently have to do manually to functionally test our product. To put things into more context, what's actually under test here is a hardware device that contains a small embedded web server that serves configuration pages.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you want Selenium IDE http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/ . Features from the site:

- Easy record and playback
- Intelligent field selection will use IDs, names, or XPath as needed
- Autocomplete for all common Selenium commands
- Walk through tests
- Debug and set breakpoints
- Save tests as HTML, Ruby scripts, or any other format
- Support for Selenium user-extensions.js file
- Option to automatically assert the title of every page
- NEW! Easy customization through plugins

I have personally never used this product however it is from official sources. The biggest road block is you would need to create a custom plugin to load your excel sheets. However it seems like it could be of major use to you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed creating a custom plugin could be an option. However, I have already tried using Selenium IDE on its own and to be honest I find that using Selenium Server together with Java a much more powerful solution, mainly because it allows me to write code that abstracts operations that I found extremely cumbersome to do when trying to use 'Selanese'.

Comment: I've been in your position myself (non technical analysts doing manual testing).  If you are comfortable learning something completely new, Cucumber is another option.  It allows non technical people to write out features they want to test in english and then you as a technical person would create the framework that makes that happen (largely through regular expressions). Link http://cukes.info.  I believe it does support java and other languages, however i've only used it in ruby.